# How to run GWT RPC in Tomcat

Tags: gwt, tomcat

I have a small application which is running fine ,but not correctly in Tomcat, I just copied all the files in my GWT's war folder to Tomcat webapps folder , when i run my application on localhost, it starts perfectly but when i try to make an RPC call via tomcat it gives me this error  attached

[image]

Any idea

thanks

NOTE::  MY RPC Service ONLY creates issue if i run in TOMCAT ,otherwise RPC working fine

My Web.xml

[image]

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
          version="2.5"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

           <!-- Servlets -->

            <servlet>
            <servlet-name>DashBoardServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.dashboard.server.DashBoardServiceImpl</servlet-class>
           </servlet>

           <servlet-mapping>
           <servlet-name>DashBoardServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/dashboardsupervisor/DashBoardServlet</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>
             <!-- Default page to serve -->
             <welcome-file-list>
             <welcome-file>DashBoardSupervisor.html</welcome-file>
            </welcome-file-list>

           </web-app>
```

My RPC Service Interface

```
            package com.dashboard.client;

           import java.util.ArrayList;


          @RemoteServiceRelativePath("DashBoardServlet")
           public interface DashBoardService extends RemoteService {

      ArrayList<FoundIntravue> fetchIntraVUE(String first, String second,  String    choice);
        String saveIntraVue(Intravue interVue, ArrayList<Networks> networksList) t   throws Exception;
      String restoreDatabase(Date selectedDate) throws Exception;
        String cleanDatabase() throws Exception;
      String saveDatabase() throws Exception;
     ArrayList<Intravue> fetchIntravuesList();


         }
```

Comment: is you url given correctly in the service ???

Comment: and that dialog is 404  not found ..so you url pattern wrong can u show us how you are making the RPC. ?

Comment: Your module web.xml file most likely contains a mistake. Can you post it along with your RPC's service interface?

Comment: Thanks for your responses , I have added my web.xml & rpc interface , please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is all there is to the problem but if you're running your application on Tomcat you do not need to run code on the GWT code server. I can see in your address bar that you're URL has `?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`in it. Try removing that.

**EDIT**:
In Eclipse you run the app with

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/Project1.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

where `Project1.html` is the page you want to load.

In Tomcat the URL should be

```
localhost:8080/project
```

Where `project` is the name of the WAR file that you put in the webapps directory.

**What ended up being the answer:**
Don't forget that your libraries have to be in `war/WEB-INF/lib`. Where `war` is the top level folder that you put in Tomcat's webapps folder.

Comment: its because . i run it via eclips , but if i run it out of eclipse by simply  localhost:8080/supervisor, this thing doesnt shows up , But do i need to do anything with my servlerts,web.xml for tomcat ? i added all the libs of my project inside tomcat/lib folder , now the error is changes , it just saying , Call Failed.

Comment: I'm a little confused here. You said that you want to run this from Tomcat but you just said above that you're running from eclipse. If you're running from eclipse the URL should look something like: `http://127.0.0.1:8888/Project.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`. If you're running from Tomcat it should be `localhost:8080/project`.

Comment: yeah u right , but i run it from eclipse from external server (i.e run as WebApplication (running on external server))   .  And yes if i eun from tomcat its like localhost:8080/project.. but it fails on rpc call .RPC is working fine in eclipse but NOT in tomcat .

Comment: Well I'm not sure. It should work. I noticed you re posted this question and an answer showed that your web.xml file was wrong but it's right here. Make sure you have the one that's shown here. More specifically: `<url-pattern>/dashboardsupervisor/DashBoardServlet</url-pattern>`

Comment: yeah , its now <url-pattern>/dashboardsupervisor/DashBoardServlet</url-pattern>, its giving me different error now (Attached screenshot above), but Again , this error doesnt shows up if i run it without tomcat in GWT hosted mode

Comment: You need to put your libraries under the lib folder which is in your WEB-INF folder within the war folder (i.e. war/WAR-INF/lib). That's the last thing I can think of.